# Changing the font style of telerik Silverlight GridViewHeaderCell overwrites the implicit style

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik

I have defined an implicit style for telerik GridViewHeaderCell which changes the background color for header cells of all grids used in the application. On some screens the caption of GridViewHeaderCell is formatted to be Bold by defining the style in that specific xaml file. This change of font overwrites the implicit GridViewHeaderCell styles applying the default Office Black style. My implicit style is given below

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewHeaderCell">        
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GridView_HeaderBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource GridView_HeaderOuterBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5 0 3 0"/>       
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource GridView_HeaderForeground}"/>
</Style>
```

Following is the style which is defined for making the caption bold

```
<Style x:Key="BoldFontStyle"
           TargetType="c:Control">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

Is there any way to stop the BoldFontStyle from overwriting the implicit style? I know it can be fixed by making Background transparent for BoldFontStyle but in that case the change has to be implemented on every screen where this BoldFontStyle is defined. I don't want to follow that approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "it can be fixed by making Background transparent for BoldFontStyle"? If you apply `Style="{StaticResource BoldFontStyle}"` to one of your `GridViewHeaderCells` that style rules. Why don't you just set the very property you actually want to change? Like so `FontWeight="Bold"`

Comment: I am sorry that you have to use Silverlight AND Telerik :| R.I.P